# Write video stream to a file from an ip address?

Tags: python, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3, urllib2

I am trying to record a live video streaming on ip 192.168.0.117:8000 but i am unable to save the video. The video is streamed from raspberry pi and pi camera. Here is the code i am trying in python:

```
import urllib2
import time

print "Recording video..."
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.0.117:8000")
filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",time.localtime())+".mp4"
f = open(filename, 'wb')

video_file_size_start = 0
video_file_size_end = 1048576 * 150
block_size = 1024

while True:
    try:
        buffer = response.read(block_size)
        if not buffer:
            break
        video_file_size_start += len(buffer)
        if video_file_size_start > video_file_size_end:
            break
        f.write(buffer)

    except Exception, e:
        logger.exception(e)

print "yes"
time.sleep(60)
f.close()
```

the file generated is of 222 bytes every time but there is nothing in the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found your code here: https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/1326ybe7yv/recording-live-video-stream-from-ip-camera-issue  There is discussion about same problem as you have. Probably your stream is MJPEG and it is rendering still only one image.

Comment: @Koxo, Thank you for your reply. But i somehow figured it out. cheers

Comment: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python I found ffmpeg python wrapper, maybe it will help you